# Using groupsVariable in COLLECT to track unique values

Tags: arangodb, aql

I'm using the following AQL to track unique visitors by month and year. Each hit contains a datetime stamp, _date, and a user name, user.

```
FOR hit IN PageHits
COLLECT month = DATE_MONTH(hit._date),year=DATE_YEAR(hit._date) INTO user=hit.user
SORT year,month
RETURN {month,year,uniqueVisitors:LENGTH(UNIQUE(user))}
```

The query calculates the correct answer but it strikes me as inefficient because the variable user contains many duplicates. The final LENGTH/UNIQUE removes these and returns the number of unique visitors.

I looked at AGGREGATE but all of the operations are statistical.

So, is there any way to add only distinct/unique values into the group variable user?

Comment: There is actually something related in the works (not yet finished):
https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/pull/5468
Once finished, it will add a `DISTINCT` operation available for use in `AGGREGATE`. Until it is there, I think your query is still the best way to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep my eye on the new feature and update this post when it's released